# Cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object- Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, iterable-unpacking

I am making a function in python which allows me to create two parallel graphs and they share their 2 axes:

```
def PlotManager(data1,data2,fig):
    f, (ax1, ax2) = fig.subplots(2, 1, sharey=True,sharex=True)

    #Plot1 sopra
    x_axis = data1.index
    #Plot and shade the area between the upperband and the lower band grey
    ax1.fill_between(x_axis,data1['Upper'],data1['Lower'], color = 'grey', alpha= 0.5)
    #Plot the closing price and the moving average
    ax1.plot(x_axis,data1['Close'],color = 'gold',lw = 3,label = 'Close Price', alpha= 0.5)
    ax1.plot(x_axis,data1['SMA'],color = 'blue',lw = 3,label = 'Simple Moving Average', alpha= 0.5)
    ax1.scatter(x_axis,data1['Buy'],color="green", lw=3,label="Buy",marker = "^", alpha=1)
    ax1.scatter(x_axis,data1['Sell'],color="red", lw=3,label="Sell",marker = "v", alpha = 1)
    #Set the title and show the image
    ax1.set_title("Bollinger Band for Amazon")
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)

    #Plot 2 Sotto
    ax2.set_title('RSI_Plot')
    ax2.plot(x_axis,data2['RSI'])
    ax2.axhline(0,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="grey")
    ax2.axhline(10,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="orange")
    ax2.axhline(20,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="green")
    ax2.axhline(30,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="red")
    ax2.axhline(70,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="red")
    ax2.axhline(80,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="green")
    ax2.axhline(90,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="orange")
    ax2.axhline(100,linestyle='--',alpha=0.5, color="grey")
```

But gives me  the `cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object` error:

```
[Command: python -u C:\Users\Nicolò\Documents\Git\ProgettoTradingBot\ProgettoTradeBot\GUIprova2.py]
C:\Users\Nicolò\Documents\Git\ProgettoTradingBot\ProgettoTradeBot\BollingerBandsFinal.py:63: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  ax = f.add_subplot(111)
C:\Users\Nicolò\Documents\Git\ProgettoTradingBot\ProgettoTradeBot\BollingerBandsFinal.py:63: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  ax = f.add_subplot(111)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolò\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 196, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolò\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 951, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Users\Nicolò\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1743, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Users\Nicolò\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1766, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolò\Documents\Git\ProgettoTradingBot\ProgettoTradeBot\GUIprova2.py", line 48, in animate
    PlotManager(BollingerBands(df,f),RSI(df,f2),f)
  File "C:\Users\Nicolò\Documents\Git\ProgettoTradingBot\ProgettoTradeBot\mostraGrafici.py", line 7, in PlotManager
    f, (ax1, ax2) = fig.subplots(2, 1, sharey=True,sharex=True)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object
```

How can i handle to this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of `plt.subplots(2, 1, ...)` is a tuple `figure, array(subplot0, subplot1)` so that you can unpack correctly to a figure and two subplots.

On the contrary the value of `fig.subplots(2, 1, ...)` is `subplot0, subplot1` (because you ALREADY have the figure…) and when you try to unpack it's equivalent to

```
f = subplot0
ax0, ax1 = subplot1
```

and this leads to `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object`

---

Because you are not using the object labeled as `f` in the following, you should write

```
ax1, ax2 = fig.subplots(2, 1, sharey=True,sharex=True)
```